# Recyclerview scroll removes margin

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I move between cardviews the margin of an imageview get removed as you can see on the screenshots.

On the first image you can see that the "views" icon is vertical aligned
and on the second image you can see that the margin is lost when I move forward and backward.

The background image is loaded with picasso and the "views" drawable is loaded in the recyclerview adapter.

[image: Not moved recyclerview]

[image: Moved recyclerview]

Comment: You can post at least an snippet of your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Man will be God if some solve issues without seeing code. :)

Can you post your item xml, and java code if you have any code written for scrolling changes.

Comment: @Jer it is an standard recyclerview construct.